# What is the underlying physics that makes Li-Fi "100 times faster" than Wi-Fi?

Tags: visible-light, radio, light-emitting-diodes

Consider [this](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/LiFi-vs-WiFi.html) webpage, which compares how the two work.

Particularly it says (and I'm paraphrasing) that Lifi transmits using light from LED bulbs and WiFi uses radio waves. Well, both are EMF waves, which travel at the same speed, and so I am confused as to how one is faster than the other. The LED bulb has a narrower field of radiance, but all light travels at the same speed; so then, why does Li-Fi perform [100 times faster](http://www.iflscience.com/technology/li-fi-internet-could-be-100-times-faster-wi-fi-0) than Wi-Fi?

Does it have anything to do with interference?

Comment: Theoretically one can transmit more information with light than with 2.5/5GHz carriers because the available modulation bandwidth would be wider, but the claims of the Li-Fi folks sound greatly (and that's an understatement) exaggerated if one takes actually achievable signal to noise ratios, realistic distances, pointing problems etc. into account. I wouldn't buy into the hype. The claim also sounds like they are thinking about modulating every room light in the world... that already reeks of desperate sales strategy.

Comment: The  '100 times faster' means the bandwidth of the information transmission, not the 'speed' of light. Just like using optical fibre, you may have Internet connection of with a 'speed' of either 10M or 100M bps.

Comment: @X.Dong: Wifi operates at up to 1900Mbit/s right now. For a LiFi link to be 100 times faster it would have to reach 190Gbit/s. That's two of the fastest fiber channels. I doubt the technology lives up to its own hype.

Comment: Since Physics.SE is not interested in this question, can I opt to have it moved to Electronics.SE?

Comment: @Klik Yes, flag for moderator attention and request that. I'll note though that I for one don't see this as off topic here.

Comment: On second thought I will leave it here for a bit longer to see if the votes change. John's answer is what I was looking for--the underlying physics explaining why LiFi is an improvement over WiFi. I do wish that the downvoters would leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending information via an EM wave requires the sender to modulate the wave. The two main ways of doing this are amplitude modulation and frequency modulation, though numerous variants exist.

Suppose you're using an EM wave with some frequency $f$, then there is a limit to the modulation frequency. In principle the maximum modulation frequency is $f/2$ but in practice the limit is considerably lower than this. Why this matters is that the modulation frequency is what limits the rate data can be sent via the EM wave. The data transmission rate can't be any greater than the modulation frequency.

Standard Wi-Fi (of the type I'm using right now while I type this) operates at various frequencies from 2.4GHz to 5.9GHz, so the maximum possible modulation frequencies would be from 1.2GHz to 2.95GHz. In practice various real world limitations mean the maximum data rates are a lot lower than this.

However the frequency of visible light is around 500THz - that's 500,000GHz! With a frequency this high the modulation frequency is not an issue. In principle light waves could be used to send data around a hundred thousand times faster then Wi-Fi. Again, the real world limit is a lot lower than this. For example the LEDs used to generate the light have a limit on how fast they can change the light intensity, and in domestic environments there will be numerous sources of stray capacitance that limit the frequencies that can be used. Nevertheless it's reasonable to suppose a useful increase in speed over Wi-Fi can be achieved.

Comment: This is all well and good, though I think the OP is getting hung up on the more fundamental concept of the difference between latency and bandwidth.

Comment: Excellent! That makes perfect sense. I have a little experience building an AM radio so I can follow your answer, though I know at very high frequencies things behave quite differently and I don't know much about that. Still, this is an excellent answer to my question.

Comment: @ChrisWhite TBH, I posted the question here (Physics.SE) because I was more concerned about the underlying physics behind LiFi that makes it an improvement over WiFi. I tried restating my question, but I may not have articulated it properly. In any case, I don't know much about latency and bandwidth so I will read up on it to be sure that I am not missing anything else.

Comment: @Klik: the guys over at the electronics SE can probably give you the gory details of exactly why WiFi speeds are so low compared to the carrier frequency.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yeah. I would really like to know their perspective as well. This sort of question can be broken down into a lot of the fields. I think I'll rephrase my question so it targets the physics side and then ask a new question over there.